how to add two different log config files in startup.cs?
How to add two different log config files in startup.cs?
We are trying to add two different config files as shown in the below code in startup.cs file under ConfigureServices(). But, we are facing an issue that the last config file is overriding the previous config file. Here we need to show both log configs(log4net.config, middlewareLogs.config).
return services.AddAbp<DTSWebHostModule>(options =>
{

    options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => {
        if (_hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config");
            f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("middlewareLogs.config");
        }
        else {
            // Load production config
            f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.Production.config");
        }
    });

    options.PlugInSources.AddFolder(Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Plugins"),
        SearchOption.AllDirectories);
});


Could you please tell me why you want to load multiple config for specific enviroment? Why you don't directly put a speific config with that two config setting?

We want to log middleware logs in a different file. It's a requirement from clients.

As far to my knowledge there is no default support of Log4Net to load multiple configs's at once. You can either try to merge them into one file or solve the issue programmatically by appending the configs's
